# Trying to call an invoke results in "Object does not match target type"

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

I'm trying to do a bit of factoring on my use of a series of Enums defined in .net

```
    private static String GetSystemTranslatedField(Type enumtype, int? val) {
        if (val == null)
            return "";

        int value = (int)val;
        String tempstr;
        if (Enum.IsDefined(enumtype, value))
        {
            tempstr = (String) enumtype.GetMethod("ToString",Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(val,null); 
            //equivalent to ((enumtype)val).ToString();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when trying to run this, i get the infamous `System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.`

As an extra question, is there a way to change the signature of my method so that only types deriving from Enum are accepted? It's not a big concern but i got curious about type restriction and couldn't find anything.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Do you want to get the string representation of the enum entry that has value `val`?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call `ToString` coming from an enum type on an `Int32` which is causing an exception in the Reflection API.

If you want to get the identifier related to a value, use `Enum.GetName` which will work on int's as well (although the documentation does not seem to indicate this):

```
if (Enum.IsDefined(enumtype, value))
{
    tempstr = Enum.GetName(enumType, value);
}
```

In fact it will return the empty string if the value is not defined, so that if could be removed as well (depending on what is in the rest of the code):

```
tempstr = Enum.GetName(enumType, value);
```

C# does not allow generic constraints to Enum derived types. It is doable on a theoretical level (it is not disallowed by the CLR) however it requires some IL weaving, which Jon Skeet demonstrated in his [Unconstrained Melody project](https://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Duh, i actually started by using GetName and then forgot about it after "simplifying" with ToString...

Answer (score 1):

[`Enum` is a class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so you can set that as your base for method signature *and avoid reflection entirely*. Try:

```
    private static String GetSystemTranslatedField(Enum enumtype, int? val) {
        if (!val.HasValue)
            return "";

        String tempstr;
        if (Enum.IsDefined(enumtype, val.Value))
        {
            tempstr = ((enumtype)val.Value).ToString(); 
        }

        ... // Rest of your code here
    }
```

Note that I cleaned your method up a bit, mainly cosmetic stuff.

Comment: I don't see how this works at all. It doesn't compile and changing the argument type to Enum makes no sense here.

Comment: Thanks for the tips; however using Enum directly here doesn't work since it's expecting a Type, not an instance of a Type (enumtype).

Comment: Ahh, my bad. I wrote this up from memory so that was probably my first mistake in regards to accuracy. :D